# How to fetch user details on simple button on click not facebook button in android?

Tags: android

I am integrating facebook login in my android app in which I want when a simple button is click then I want to fetch user details.I do not want to place facebook login button. How can I do that

here is my code:-

```
private Button loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));
        }
    });
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.d("Success", "Login");
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    Log.e("JSON:", object.toString());
                                    String user_ID = null;
                                    try {
                                        user_ID = object.getString("id");
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    CFacbookStorage facebookstorage = new CFacbookStorage();
                                    facebookstorage.setM_UserId(user_ID);
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CFacebookDeatails.class);
                                    i.putExtra("user_data", facebookstorage);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    AccessToken token;
    token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();


    if (token == null) {
        //Means user is not logged in
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "init: facebooklogin   " + AccessToken.USER_ID_KEY + "   " + AccessToken.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY + "  ");
    }
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

CFacbookStorage class code:-

```
    public static CFacbookStorage cFacbookStorage;

public String getM_UserId() {
    return m_UserId;
}

public void setM_UserId(String m_UserId) {
    this.m_UserId = m_UserId;
}

public String m_UserId;

public static CFacbookStorage getInstance(){
    if (cFacbookStorage==null){
        cFacbookStorage = new CFacbookStorage();
    }
    return cFacbookStorage;
}
```

}

CFacebookDetail

```
private TextView info;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);

}
```

in this code I am getting error in loginButton.registerCallback(){}

Comment: You mean you want facebook login to work at one go ??

Comment: yes ......................................................

Comment: If you are fetching information from facebook... And dont want to show facebook login instead show some different button then you are ethically  not right... And facebook do not let you fetch the information unless the user agrees to allow your app to access their basic information... Atleast then user will get to know that information is being fetched from fb.. So single click and fetch profile information is never possible.

Answer (score 1):

used your button in xml file then after in oncreate of activity use below code:

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        // Application code
                                        response.getError();
                                        Log.e("JSON:", object.toString());
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        AccessToken token;
        token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();


        if (token == null) {
            //Means user is not logged in
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "init: facebooklogin   " + AccessToken.USER_ID_KEY + "   " + AccessToken.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY + "  ");
        }
```

after add below code on button click event:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SignInActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

            }
        });
```

the put in that activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: String user_id=object.getString("id").toString(); 
String email=object.getString("email").toString();
String name=object.getString("name").toString();
String gender =object.getString("gender").toString();

Comment: I am like that:- public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
          try {
           String user_Id = object.getString("id").toString();
           CFacbookStorage.getInstance().setM_UserId(user_Id);
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CFacebookDeatails.class);
           startActivity(i);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
          // Application code
          response.getError();
          Log.e("JSON:", object.toString());
         }
        });

Comment: is this correct I am setting user data in Storage class and then navigating to another activity where I want to show user data

Comment: are you pass that user data with intent?

Comment: no first I set user data in Storage class then navigate to another class and in that class I retreive data from storage class

Comment: you want user data in CFacebookDetails activity?

Comment: first in CFacbookStorage class implement Serializable interface then

CFacbookStorage facebookstorage=new CFacbookStorage();
facebookstorage.setM_UserId(user_ID);
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CFacebookDeatails.class); 
i.putExtra("user_data", facebookstorage);
startActivity(i);

in CFacebookDeatails activity
CFacbookStorage facebookstorage=getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user_data");
here in CFacbookStorage store all user data.

also see this link for refe.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Comment: but it does not fetch any user data

Comment: give me your hole code with activity and object class

Comment: where is your CFacbookStorage class and CFacebookDeatails activity?

Comment: CFacbookStorage facebookstorage=getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user_data");
add this line in CFacebookDeatails activity and do public class  CFacbookStorage **implement Serializable**

Comment: 09-02 11:26:32.109 12296-12296/com.example.devui1.socialintegration D/TAG: init: facebooklogin   user_id   access_token

Comment: then use this for get user id and save into CFacbookStorage object

Comment: but i am not getting any value in Log.e("JSON:", response.toString());

Comment: when I user Facebook login Button then I retrieve user information successfull ,,,,

Comment: by doing this way I don;t

Comment: in above code you put imagebutton onclick event two time remove any one from that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by overriding you facebook button view with that of your appcompat button using FrameLayout. Something like this :

```
           <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/facebook"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fb_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            </FrameLayout>
```

onClick Implementation :

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == custom_fb_login) {
            fb_login.performClick();
        }
    }
```

FbButton Click:

```
 private View.OnClickListener handleClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
             case R.id.facebook:
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Login.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
                    break;
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: see here problem is that I dont want facebook button text change to logout always remain lig in

Comment: You should now worry for that as facebook's original button will get hidden by your own facebook button image as you will be using a framelayout. Have you tried executing my xml code?